# Profile values becoming null from one form to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile

I am saving some values in profile as below

```
            Profile.StudentPart.studentid= dt.Rows[0]["Stu_ID"].ToString();
            Profile.StudentPart.studentemail = useridtxt.Text;
            Profile.Save();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(useridtxt.Text, false);
            Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/childrenaccount"));
```

but when navigate to  `Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/childrenaccount"));` url
the value of the profile becoming null in page load can any one help me.

Comment: Can you provide what `Profile.Save()` functions does? Additionally, how this `~/childrenaccount` page/action look like?

Comment: it will save the values to the profile

Comment: Ok but are you loading an entity once more after redirecting? Is is not like WinForms application, server doesn't fetch your changes automatically.

Comment: ok , what do to save the changes to the profile , when redirected to next page , that is i want the value of that profile in redirected page , how to get it???

Comment: Provide full code for `Save()` method and `~/childrenaccount` page/action so it will be possible to give you correct answer.

Comment: the url is routed and save() method is inbuilt function

Comment: Ok so what `Profile` is? Is it built-in function from some ORM? I know that URL is routed - please share the code which hits null values after redirecting.

Comment: using profile we can save a value and use it whenever we want to. and in page load itself it is becoming null

Comment: Your saying quite obvious things yet you still haven't shared your code that anyone could look into it as I requested.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
            string test = Profile.StudentPart.studentemail;
            string id = Profile.StudentPart.studentid;
            
    }  this is the page load but the values of test and id is null

Comment: Okay but from this `Profile` comes from? Is it an entity? Can you show us code? Is it something generated by EF? Is it initialized somehow?

Comment: see this link  http://pastie.org/10177702#1

Comment: Is it full code of `Profile` class?

Comment: yes it is the full code

Comment: Not sure I can help cause it is hard to imagine whole concept but I believe that after redirecting you are not fetching your entity from DB, that's why you are getting nulls.

Comment: No I am storing it from DB only , but no problem leave it i finished it in another way , Thanks for tendency to help :) :X